# Creating image frame not displaying in simulator

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cgrect

I have an app that captures the users signature, myviewcontroller displays the signature capture. I'm attempting to create a rectangle in the center of the screen that is centered for this to happen using CGRect. When I run this I get no errors, but I get the picture below and I can't figure out what is causing this. 
Within the CGRect code, I am trying to have the rectangle that is created be centered in the middle of the screen, and the target device is ipad. I've posted both the .h and .m files, the .m file is incomplete as the rest has to do with the code used to capture the signature then save it.

Any help would be appreciated. 
[image: Simulation]

//MyViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *mySignatureImage;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastContactPoint1, lastContactPoint2, currentPoint;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect imageFrame;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL fingerMoved;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float navbarHeight;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) UIImageView* imageView;


    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSData*image;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    //Save and cancel buttons

    - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender;


    @end

//MyViewController.m

#import "MyViewController.h"



@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize mySignatureImage;
@synthesize lastContactPoint1, lastContactPoint2, currentPoint;
@synthesize imageFrame;
@synthesize fingerMoved;
@synthesize navbarHeight;
@synthesize image;
@synthesize imageView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(
                                   CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetMidX(imageView.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetMidY(imageView.frame),
                                   CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame),
                                   CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame));

//    //allocate an image view and add to the main view
    mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    mySignatureImage.frame = imageFrame;
    mySignatureImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:mySignatureImage];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code (except for `[super viewDidLoad]`) in `viewDidLoad` to a later stage, such as `viewWillAppear`. During `viewDidLoad` the layout of the views is not yet complete so their bounds/frames are not yet set to their final values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so I moved all the code to viewWillAppear, after the viewDidload method and this results in a white screen on simulation with the save and cancel buttons still present

Comment: Since `mySignatureView` is initialized with a `nil` image, and its `backgroundColor` is set to white, the white screen is the expected result. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: I understand why the white screen is displayed however I was expecting an image rectangle that would allow the user to type draw their name. Something that wouldn't take up the whole screen but would probably take up most of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
```

with:

```
mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, doing that resulted in the same screen on the simulator. I do however get a warning 'local declaration of 'imageframe' hides instance variable' could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, it can be. Try to rename it in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Is imageView already initialized in the viewDidLoad method? Because if it is nil, both CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame) and CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame) will return 0, and the dimensions of the image will be 0 and 0. I think that is the problem.

Comment: I have it under CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake (

Comment: So should I rename that one, or the actual image view?

Comment: Rename the imageFrame variable in the viewDidLoad method, you need to do it in  2 places.

Comment: When you call CGRectMake(...), imageView is nil or not?

Comment: imageView is OK with this name, my only concern is that you probably forget to initialize it

Comment: at the end of viewDidLoad, write this code NSLog(@"imageFrame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageFrame)); and let me know what are the results.

Comment: So I've renamed CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake ( to CGRect imageSignature = CGRectMake ( and mySignatureImage.frame = imageFrame; to mSignatureImage.frame = imageSignature; results in the same warning, where these not the two places it needed to be changed in? I don't see it anywhere else. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've added the NSLong code I get this 2014-08-07 21:10:59.317 FlyerList[7002:607] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8c63d40 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
(lldb)

Comment: then imageframe= {{0,0}, {0,0}}

Comment: I see, I think imageSignature frame is set to invalid value, because it is not supposed to crash. Try to write instead NSLog(@"mySignatureImage = %@", mySignatureImage); at the end of viewDidLoad. Let me know if the result is nil.

Comment: Here is the result : mySignatureImage=<UIImageView: 0x8cbc510; frame = (384 512; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8cc8960>> - (null)

Comment: You see, 0 and 0 represent the width and height, that's the reason it is not visible.

Comment: makes perfect sense, so I set the width, and height to 50,50 and now I get the rectangle in the center of the screen! Thank you. I still see mySignatureImage= {{0,0}, {0,0}} in the log, I assume that's because it's set to nil is that correct and should it be a problem?

Comment: probably yes, because of that.